Where is the documentation for /sys/block/md*/md/fail_last_dev
What can we do with this file: /sys/block/md0/md/fail_last_dev?
I cannot find any information about it in the md man page. In the section SYSFS INTERFACE it says: This  interface  is documented more fully in the file Documentation/md.txt. But I cannot find fail_last_dev there either. It's only in the code.

If it's only in the code, then look in the code, which has this comment:
/*
 * Setting fail_last_dev to true to allow last device to be forcibly removed
 * from RAID1/RAID10.
 */

It looks like this will let you remove the last remaining device in a RAID1 or RAID0 device.
(This may be a good opportunity for you to make your first contribution to the Linux kernel by submitting a patch that updates Documentation/md.txt.)
